# How do you set a random probability of a object appearing on screen javascript (for a game)

Tags: javascript

I want an item to appear every now and then. Usually one item appear that give +10 score but i want a rare item to appear at a random chance that give more points.

Ive already tried something that looks like this except repurposed for what i need

```
if (Math.random() * 100 < 80) {
  sendMessage("hi");
}
else if (Math.random() * 100 < 5) {
  sendMessage("bye");
}
```

I expected for a gold thing to appear but it never did

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first determine what you want the probabilities of these events to be and how frequently you want them to occur.

Presumably you'd have some short time interval between these events, say for example 60 seconds. And then the chance of a rare one could be 5%. So your example at the moment seems to be a bit off because of your else statement.

```
const rand => Math.rand() * 100;

if(rand() <= 80){
  // 80% of any reward appearing
  if(rand() <= 5){
    // Give the super reward, 5% chance
  } else {
    // Give the regular reward
  }
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: your `else` should be outside, actually there is no need to add that else, because the regular reward will be always given if the first clause is not valid.
for example, the value `50` would give the reward of the `80%` and the reward inside the else, because it is bigger than `5`

Comment: I'm working off what I interpreted from the OP's original code. And in my example there's an 80% chance of receiving any award, and subsequently a 4% chance overall of receiving a rare reward. Of course there's also a 20% chance of nothing, the intended behaviour can be tweaked quite easily depending on what they are after.

Answer (score 0):

basically you need to calculate once the random probability and then assign the reward based on your logic.

```js
const normalProbability = 80;
const epicProbability = 5;

const obtainReward = () => {
  const calculated = Math.random() * 100;
  if (calculated <= normalProbability && calculated > epicProbability) {
    console.log(`normal probability to appear a common object... you got ${calculated}%`)
    return calculated;
  } else if (calculated <= epicProbability) {
    console.log(`epic probability to appear a common object, you got ${calculated}%`);
    return calculated;
  }
  console.log(`no reward because you got... ${calculated}%`);
  return calculated;
}

console.log("starting the automatic process")
setInterval(() => obtainReward(), 3000);
```